# AQGridView: Problem when load nib file

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nib, aqgridview

I'm working with AQGridView, and when I load the nib file, he also load an square white ahead of elements.

In this project, I also implemented

```
- (CGSize) portraitGridCellSizeForGridView: (AQGridView *) gridView;

  {

      return CGSizeMake(250, 400);

  }
```

And when I change this values, the size of square also change.

Looks like that: http://cl.ly/1S223X2u23081Y1i3U0R

How i fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as the code for your cellForItemAtIndex and what's in your nib file.  There may be an interaction with contentView, but need more info to respond.